# Get notified about unsuccessful back swipe gestures in UINavigationController

Tags: objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uigesturerecognizer

I have a UINavigationController subclass, which manages a custom navigation bar. This navigation bar's look depends on the top view controller. I ask the top view controller about the type of the bar to be displayed when `-pushViewController:animated:` or `-popViewControllerAnimated:` happens.

The problem is, that the navigation bar type change is played when the user starts swiping but I could not find any event which tells me that the swipe was successful or not, so if the user cancels the swipe, I stuck on the previous view controller with the desired navigation bar look of the one below it in the navigation stack.

I have tried `UINavigationControllerDelegate`, but neither `-navigationController:didShowViewController:animated:` nor `-navigationController:didShowViewController:animated:` gets called. My second thought was to use `interactiveGestureRecognizer`, but it seems it it ends successfully both on successful and cancelled back swipe, and the `topViewController` is also still the same when the recognizer event is called.

I know, that the top view controller's `-viewDidAppear` will be called again upon cancelled swipe, but I don't want my users to implement any logic in their controllers to support my navigation implementation.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using the UINavigationControllerDelegate, you can rely on its callbacks to know when a viewController is going to be displayed or not.

[Getting interactivePopGestureRecognizer dismiss callback/event](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21155863/2308258)